# StreetViewPanorama - how to change to other image

Tags: javascript, google-street-view

I have a little problem and I can't find the solution; maybe someone will know how to fix it.
I have code below where Google `StreetViewPanorama` and everything (drag, zoom) is working okay. But when I init other image in this object, after the image loads in the object, it stops working: no zooming, edges are displayed, dragging is half-working.
Destroying object before changing image doesn't work.
Maybe is there some method to update this object?

```
function initPano() {
    // Set up Street View and initially set it visible. Register the
    // custom panorama provider function. Set the StreetView to display
    // the custom panorama 'reception' which we check for below.
    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('map'), {
            pano: 'reception',
            visible: true,
            panoProvider: getCustomPanorama
        }
    );
}
// Return a pano image given the panoID.
function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
    // Note: robust custom panorama methods would require tiled pano data.
    // Here we're just using a single tile, set to the tile size and equal
    // to the pano "world" size.
    return 'img/pano-1.jpg'; // <----------- HERE
}
// Construct the appropriate StreetViewPanoramaData given
// the passed pano IDs.
function getCustomPanorama(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
    if(pano === 'reception') {
        return {
            location: {
                pano: 'reception',
                description: 'Description'
            },
            links: [],
            // The text for the copyright control.
            copyright: 'Imagery (c) 2010 Google',
            // The definition of the tiles for this panorama.
            tiles: {
                tileSize: new google.maps.Size(1024, 512),
                worldSize: new google.maps.Size(1024, 512),
                // The heading in degrees at the origin of the panorama
                // tile set.
                centerHeading: 105,
                getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out something like this, and for now it's working corectly..

```
var panorama;
function initialize() {
    var panoOptions = {
        pano: 'sfera-4',
        visible: true,
        panoProvider: getCustomPanorama
    }
    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('map'), 
        panoOptions
    );
}
function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(pano,zoom,tileX,tileY) {
    return 'i/'+pano+'s.jpg';
}
function getCustomPanorama(pano,zoom,tileX,tileY) {
    switch(pano) {
        case 'sfera-4':
            return {
                location: {
                    pano: 'sfera-4',
                    description: 'Sfera 4'
                },
                copyright: 'Description',
                tiles: {
                    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(4096,2048),
                    worldSize: new google.maps.Size(4096,2048),
                    centerHeading: 0,
                    getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
                }
            };
        break;
        case 'sfera-7':
            return {
                location: {
                    pano: 'sfera-7',
                    description: 'Sfera 7'
                },
                copyright: 'Description',
                tiles: {
                    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(4096,2048),
                    worldSize: new google.maps.Size(4096,2048),
                    centerHeading: 0,
                    getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
                }
            };
        break;
    }
}
function setMap(id) {
    panorama.setPano('sfera-'+id);
}
```

for changing image I just calling setMap(7)